# Getting sun.security.validator.ValidatorException when trying to convert the IBMMQ (Queue and Topic) REST API to Java

Tags: rest, ibm-mq

I need to dynamically create Queue and Topic in IBMMQ. With the Help of SO people , I am able to get the REST API Endpoints and it is working fine via CURL, but when i tried to change the REST API to Java Code , getting the below Exception. kindly help

-------------------complete Code-------------------------

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class IbmmqQueue {


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
            URL url = new URL("https://localhost:9443/ibmmq/rest/v1/admin/qmgr/QM1/queue");
            HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            http.setRequestMethod("POST");
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            http.setRequestProperty("license", "accept");
            http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46cGFzc3cwcmQ=");
            http.setRequestProperty("ibm-mq-rest-csrf-token", ";");

            String data = "{\n   \"name\": \"fourthQueue1\",\n   \"type\": \"local\",\n \n   \"storage\" : {\n      \"maximumDepth\" : 5000\n   }\n}";

            byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
            stream.write(out);

            System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + http.getResponseMessage());
            http.disconnect();
    


        }
```

-----Exception message------

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at IbmmqQueue.main(IbmmqQueue.java:30)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 19 more
```

Comment: Does it work if you use http? It looks like a certificate problem when using https. Knowing that would help you narrow done where to look for problems. You haven't told us anything about your certificate set up so it's hard to give more advice than that.

Comment: What type of cert does the https port have?  You need to add the issuer that signed it or the cert itself if self signed to you java process trust store.  Default trust store is a file called cacerts under the java path in the security folder.   There may be a java system property to tell java to ignore that it doesn't trust the cert presented.   You can also create a new trust store and set a Java system property to point to that instead cacerts.  Default password for cacerts is changeit.